# Preserve New Line in Laravel Request

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel to pass a JSON And storing the request into a model
The JSON that I'm passing is of the form

```
{
    "key": "GEnFcIB5UBScbwrM9OfBqYzY0/8=\r\n",
}
```

But when storing it to the DB, the key is stored as GEnFcIB5UBScbwrM9OfBqYzY0/8=

This is what I get when I dump the request

```
  Request {#42
      #json: ParameterBag {#24
        #parameters: array:1 [
          "key" => "GEnFcIB5UBScbwrM9OfBqYzY0/8="
          ]
      }

        ...

      #content: "{"key":"GEnFcIB5UBScbwrM9OfBqYzY0/8=\r\n"}",

        ...

    }
```

As you can see the #content is showing the "\r\n", but $request->key discards it and eventually is not saved in the DB

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backslashes?

Comment: Sounds silly but you can save json also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might very well be due to trimming.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization

> By default, Laravel includes the TrimStrings and ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware in your application's global middleware stack. These middleware are listed in the stack by the  App\Http\Kernel class. These middleware will automatically trim all incoming string fields on the request, as well as convert any empty string fields to null. This allows you to not have to worry about these normalization concerns in your routes and controllers.
>
> If you would like to disable this behavior, you may remove the two middleware from your application's middleware stack by removing them from the $middleware property of your  App\Http\Kernel class.